# After setting EnableHexNumpad=1, hex Unicode alt-codes work well in Notepad++ and Excel but have a strange behavior in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode, alt-code

I try to summarize what is the behavior I see, keeping into consideration that Windows can't handle codes above `0xFFFF`:

1. Word works flawlessly with decimal code point inserted through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>decimal</kbd>. As an example, no problem in inserting even  as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>128512</kbd>,  (As a side note, Notepad++ doesn't manage this shortcut and put `\0` in the file. Excel ignores the input.)
2. Word accepts hex code for low code point blocks. However for some (many?) higher Unicode blocks, if there aren't hex `A-F` digits in the code, the code is interpreted as decimal unavoidably. As an example, let's take the "Ethiopic" code block, which begins at `0x1200` and enter in Word the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+1200</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+1201</kbd>, ..., <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+120F</kbd>, i.e. the first row of the block. We would expect to insert the characters `ሀሁሂሃሄህሆሇለሉሊላሌልሎሏ`. Instead I see `ҰұҲҳҴҵҶҷҸҹሊላሌልሎሏ`, so that last six characters are correct, while first ten are not: they are from code points `0x4B0`-`0x4B9`, or in decimal format `1200`-`1209`. The error is apparent: when there aren't `A-F` digits in the code, it is interpreted as decimal even if the <kbd>+</kbd> is prepended. Notepad++ and Excel work as expected for these cases. This seems to be linked to an internal association between available font glyphs, but I didn't get any definitive conclusion.
3. For completely unsupported code blocks, `A-F` digits aren't considered and only the numbers concur, interpreted as decimals. As an example, let's enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+30C4</kbd>. Instead of the `ツ` katakana I obtain `İ`, which is code point `0x130` or decimal `304` (the original `30C4` string without `C`). Even with hex codes of more than 4 digits one has the same behavior: attempting to insert <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+1f600</kbd>, the emoji of the point 1., inputs `0x640` or decimal `1600`. In Excel this latter alt code inserts `0xF600` (verified with `UNICODE()` function), which is invalid and shown as `` but, keeping in mind the 4-digit limitation, this seems reasonable.

So, is it all about a simply misconfigured system, or is there some option I can explore to revert to expected behavior (Word 365 MSO (16.0.14131.20278) 32-bit)?

Comment: [This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0) might be relevant as it mentions the option to prefix U+. It's a slighty different apporach but it might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I would chalk this up to bugs in Word, which is well-known for carrying
ancient methods that may work differently than newly-programmed ones.

For example, typing in Word "1200 alt x" gives `ሀ` as expected,
while typing "alt + 1200" gives `Ұ`.

The interesting part here is that the Unicode hex code of `Ұ` is `4B0`.
I note that decimal `1200` converted into hex is `4B0`.
I also note that "alt + 4B0" also gives `Ұ`.

From this I conclude that Word will do the following irrational test:
If after "alt +" the entered string contains only digits ("1200")
it will assume that it's written in decimal, but if it contains one of
the letters `a-f` ("4B0") it is taken as hexadecimal.

This theory of mine is born out by your tests - when your entered
codes started including the letters `a-f`, they were interpreted
correctly as hex. As long as they only contained decimal digits,
they were wrongly interpreted as being decimal.

The implementation by Microsoft of the `EnableHexNumpad` option
seems to be very flawed.

Word cannot be fixed by you or me. The most you can do is signal the
problem to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub (which wouldn't help much).

If you need a third-party utility that doesn't have such gotchas,
you may for example use the ancient
[UnicodeInput](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/UnicodeInput.shtml)
which still works in Windows 10 for entering Unicode. It intercepts
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and puts up a dialog box where the Unicode
can be entered.